# Laravel limit records with pagination

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-pagination

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and when working with pagination, I cannot limit the result. When I try with `$query->take($x)`, the result is x records, but when I try with `$query->take($x)->paginate(5)`, it give me all records with 5 records per page.
Could anyone work with laravel pagination could give a hint to resolve that problem?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It is not about just fetching the records, you will have to add a number of features in the grid e.g. may be export, searching, filtration etc. I have used Nayjest grid and would recommend you to use another one. I came across and issue and contacted the community and that's what is their reply:

`At all, I would recommend to migrate to next major version of grids that is moved to separate repository: https://github.com/view-components/grids 
Tip: If you have a lot of usage of nayjest/grids, you can use view-components/grids in parallel for your new reports.`

so you should go for:

```
https://github.com/view-components/grids
```

Comment: It's the good library, but my question is not about how we display it, it just how we select it, because when I try to get the raw sql of $query->take($x), it's really: select... limit x.
But when I'm going on with paginate, it looks like paginate() ignore take() function